# How does ooo-thumbnailer work?

Tags: libreoffice

The program `ooo-thumbnailer` does not work. I have installed it from the above ppa and restarted nautilus, of course, but no thumbnails whatsoever are created.

When I call `ooo-thumbnailer` from the command line I gen the following:

```
convert convert: Improper image header (/tmp/gmJ6Jks5).
```

It is something it has to do with the imagemagick convert utility. I have installed the `graphics-imagemagick-compat` package, but I also tried to substitute that with the `imagemagick` package. In this case `ooo-thumbnailer` still doesn't work but the error code is different (I don't recall precisely now).

I also tried to compile `ooo-thumbnailer` and `imagemagick` from source with no success.

Anyone knows what the problem might be?

System: Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5):

I've just discovered that this is due to a minor bug in the "ooo-thumbnailer" package.
Until a new version is released, I've managed to get thumbnails displayed again in this way:

1) As root, create a new (plain text) file, which is missing:

```
/usr/share/thumbnailers/ooo.thumbnailer
```

2) Open this new file with your text editor (e.g. gedit or medit) and paste the following text:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]

TryExec=ooo-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/ooo-thumbnailer %i %o %s
MimeType=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;
```

3) Save this file and restart Nautilus using this command in user terminal:

```
nautilus -q
```

You should now have thumbnails generated and displayed for all supported file types like ODT and so on...

Comment: It is a shame that this hasn't been fixed in 14.04...

Comment: @EdVillegas Yes, it is still unfixed, and it seems the maintenance has been stopped. I contacted the developer about LibreOffice version and Server/client version because I would like keep thumbnails of all new files. I have a thread and a bounty about the issue here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288654/16920